# Control high order moments by lower order moment?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics

Let $X$ be a random variable and suppose that we have $E(|X|) <+\infty$ and $E(|X|^2)<+\infty$. In particulary, I can find a constant C such that 
$$
E(|X|^2) < C\quad\quad (1)
$$
I consider the higher moments of $X$ as $E(|X|^{2p})$ where $p>1$. I have two questions:

1) Can we always conclude that $E(|X|^{2p}) < + \infty$ by using (1) (maybe not!) or it depends on the properties of $X$?

2) Suppose that $E(|X|^{2p}) < + \infty$ and if I want to find an upper bound for $E(|X|^{2p})$. Is there any inequality that allow us to find the upper bound by using (1)?

Thank you in advance for any answer.

Comment: Answer is no to both questions when p>1. But the answer is yes when p <1

Comment: For example, knowing $E(|X|^4)$ puts a natural upper bound on $E(|X|^2)$ (the square root) but not the other way round.

Answer (score 0):

To see the answer is no to both questions, you can consider the following counter examples

### 1. We can have $\mathbb E(X^{2p})=\infty$

Let us assume $P(X)\propto\frac1{|X|^\nu+1}$. If $\nu>1$, it is a well defined probability distribution, which has a finite $\mathbb{E}(|X|)$ for $\nu>2$ and a finite  $\mathbb{E}(|X|^2)$ for $\nu>3$.

Actually we have
\begin{align}
  \mathbb{E}(|X|^\mu)&\text{ finite} & \text{if }&\mu<\nu\\
  \mathbb{E}(|X|^\mu)&=+\infty & \text{if }&\mu\ge\nu,
\end{align}
therefore, a good choice of $\nu$ allows set the rank after which all moments are infinite, even if all the lower moments are bounded

### 2. We can have really high finite $\mathbb E(X^{2p})$, even when  $\mathbb E(X^{2p})\le C$

Just look at the following simple probability distribution for $X$, defined for $\varepsilon>0$:
\begin{align}
 P(X=0)&=1-\varepsilon; &
 P\left(X=\sqrt{\frac C\varepsilon}\right)&=\varepsilon. 
\end{align}
We have then, assuming $\varepsilon\ll 1$ and $p>1$
\begin{align}
  \mathbb E(|X|)&=\sqrt{\varepsilon C}&\ll \sqrt{C}\\ 
  \mathbb E(|X|^2)&=\varepsilon C&\\
  \mathbb E(|X|^{2p})&=\frac{C^p}{\varepsilon^{p-1}}& \gg C^p 
\end{align}
Chosing a small enough $\varepsilon$ allows to choose a $E(|X|^{2p})$ arbitrary large, but finite, while keeping the first two moments below $C$.